# Global/SESSION PHP Array/Variable without content

Tags: php

I have a huge problem which I can't seem to fix. I got 2 files. `insertDB.php`(for writing content into my database) & `mail.php`(for sending me a mail if something got written into databse). Because I don't want the mail stuff in the same file as the SQL-Statements, I created the `mail.php` file.
Now I want to pass Variables or an Array from insertDB to mail. It works in every other file I'm using but it's not working here.

```
<?php
//insertDB.php
Session_Start();
include 'dbconnect.php';
$login = $_SESSION['login'];

$num = $_mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['num']);
$date = $_mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['date']);
$user = $_mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$program = $_mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['program']);
$name = $_mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$path = $_mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['path']);

$mailData = [$num, $date, $user, $program, $name, $path];

$_SESSION['mailData'] = $mailData;
// var_dump($_SESSION['mailData']); <- outputs array WITH content
$insert = "INSERT INTO Zeichnungen (Num, Date, User, Program, Name, Path, Info, Leer)
  VALUES ('$num', '$date', '$user', '$program', '$name', '$path', '', '$login')";
if ($_result = $_mysqli->query($insert)) {
  header('Location: mail.php');
}
?>


<?php
//mail.php
Session_Start();
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
include '/opt/composer/vendor/autoload.php';
include 'insertDB.php';
$login = $_SESSION['login'];
var_dump($_SESSION['mailData']);
?>
/* Output I see in Browser from mail.php -> var_dump($_SESSION['mailData']); : */
array(6) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(0) "" [5]=> string(0) "" }
```

What is the problem? Why does it have no content but the 6 keys?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the code, there is nothing obvious to me that can cause `var_dump` to print 6 empty strings. The obvious explanation is that your `$_POST` is empty. You might have an issue with how this POST is made. That said, you should at least use functions for this. Define a `sendEmail(array $mailData) { ... }` function and call it. Using the session to store these variables is not a good practice. It is unnecessary global state and will eventually make this code even more difficult to follow.

Comment: Good thought but it's not empty. My ``$insert = "INSERT INTO Zeichnungen...`` works fine and inserts everything perfectly into my table. When I comment ``header('Location: mail.php');`` and uncomment ``var_dump($_SESSION['mailData']);`` in insertDB.php it outputs this: ``array(6) { [0]=> string(6) "Number" [1]=> string(4) "Date" [2]=> string(4) "User" [3]=> string(5) "Visio" [4]=> string(4) "Name" [5]=> string(4) "Path" } ``. (I wrote Number, Date, User... into the Post)

Comment: I pasted your code into two files and it just works (session contains the correct data). The problem is somewhere else not in the code you provided. This is difficult to debug this way. As I said, don't use the session for this, if this data does not survive through multiple requests and you don't want to use classes, at least pass them using functions.

Comment: How excactly would I have to pass them using functions? Maybe got a link for that?

Comment: You have several examples in https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php. Define the functions in one file and note that you must `include` that file before being able to use them. Do not mix concerns, ie: your mail function should not set HTTP headers, and your database function should not access the $_SESSION or $_POST variables.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, there is nothing obvious to me that can cause `var_dump()` to print 6 empty strings. Running the provided code does not reproduce your problem (despite unnecessarily calling `start_session()` again, but that has no effect other than a warning).

This is difficult to debug this way. Don't use the session for this if this data does not survive through multiple requests. If you don't want to use classes, at least pass the data to functions with one responsibility. Using the session to store these variables is not a good practice. It is unnecessary global state and will eventually make this code even more difficult to follow and debug.

You have several examples in http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php. Define the functions in one file and note that you must include that file before being able to use them. Do not mix concerns, ie: your mail function should not set HTTP headers, and your database function should not access the $_SESSION or $_POST variables.

For example, in insertIntoDb.php (less fields for clarity) and using functions:

```php
<?php

// ... (necessary mysqli includes, etc.)

function insertIntoDB(array $formData) {
  // we escape the data here, this escaping is DB specific.
  $num = $_mysqli->real_escape_string($formData['num']);
  $date = $_mysqli->real_escape_string($formData['date']);
  $login = $formData['login'];

  $insert = "
    INSERT INTO SomeTable (Num, Date, Login)
    VALUES ('$num', '$date', '$login');
  ";

  // it's better not to have other side effects here
  // if everything goes right, we just continue
  $result = $_mysqli->query($insert);

  if (!$result) {
    die("Database error");
  }
}
```

In your mail.php file:

```php
<?php

include 'insertIntoDb.php';
include 'sendEmail.php';

// we read the POST and other values here
// constructing an associative array is an 
// option if not using objects.
$formData = [
  'num' => $_POST['num'],
  'date' => $_POST['date'],
  'login' => $_SESSION['login'],
];

// using the functions
insertIntoDb($formData);
sendEmail($formData); // defined in sendEmail.php, not in example.

// this point is reached when everything works, 
// no need to control flow...

header('Location: success.php'); // perhaps "thanks" message.
```

Comment: You said: "your database function should not access the $_POST variables." But I need to access it because it's a form I have to fill with the conent I want to write into the DB. Then, I still haven't find any "right" way to get all this working. Sadly, php.net doesn't help me in any way. Can you explain how it's meant to be?

Comment: Well, tried it a few times and just because I used ``include 'mail.php';`` the whole code of ``insertDB.php`` stopped working. Made it a comment and it worked again (still no mail though)

Comment: I extended the example with reading the $_POST outside that function and passing the data using an [associative array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). This way you divide and conquer. Each function has, well... a function.

Comment: Isn't it a possible security risk to take the ``$_POST[]`` Variables and store them into an Array without escaping them first? Because of these thoughts I escaped them before doing anything. And basically what happens is that the form I fill runs the mail.php file which stores my input in an array, runs the 2 functions from the other files and then heads to where I want it to, am I right?

Comment: Storing them is an array not a risk per se. The security concerns are different for storing and for sending emails. The idea in the example is that you should not couple reading those variables with your database code or the email code. You can apply a different strategy to sanitize what goes in the email, after all, you might not care about HTML in that database, but you probably don't want it in the email. You could additionally use [`filter_input_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php) or similar methods when constructing your data structure.

Comment: As I was waiting for an answer I tried what you did. Inserting into DB works fine. But as soon as I include the mail.php (file to send the mail) it crashes and my page goes white instead of where it should be. Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

as many have said, the code is clean and should work. The other possible culprit is the following line

```
header('Location: mail.php');
```

The php function header() clears all GETs & POSTs when client leaves current page.

Instead make **mail.php** a function then include **mail.php** in **insertDB.php**

**NB: try to adopt OOP coding particulary when dealing with PHP**

Comment: `header()` here is only called **after** the `$_POST` variable was read. It odes not affect the `$_SESSION` hence can't cause this behavior with this import order, assuming mail.php is the entry point.

Comment: Just read that now. insertDB.php is the entry point. But before doing anything else I'm escaping the ``$_POST`` variables and storing them into normal variables. Also tried to store them in ``$_SESSION`` and ``$_GLOBALS`` but both didn't work. ``$_varName`` also didn't change anything.

Comment: great since the whole thing cannot be reproduced .. try save all data in session and do insertion into db from mail.php...

Comment: Well, as I wrote as a comment on the other answer, I can perfectly insert my data into the table. BUT as soon as I include the mail.php (to send the mail) and uncomment   
```use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;```  
nothing works anymore and my page turns white. As long as they are comments everything works but I can't send mails without them (sendEmail function does nothing now)